# How can I make Apache on an amazon ec2 linux box using the elastic IP instead of the private IP?

Tags: api, amazon-ec2, centos

I've migrated a website to Amazon ec2 that hooks into a service we are using that is installed on another server (not on Amazon). Access to the API for that service is IP-restricted and done by sending XML data using *http_build_query* & *stream_context_create* in PHP.

If I want to connect to the service from a new server, I need to ask the vendor to add the new IP first. I did that by sending the Elastic IP to them, but it doesn't work. 
While trying to debug, I noticed that the output for $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] is the private IP of the ec2 instance.
I assume that the server on the other side is receiving the same data, so it tries to authenticate the private IP.
I've asked the vendor to allow access from the private IP as well – it's not implemented yet, so I'm not sure if that solves the problem, but as far as I understand the way their API works, it will then try to parse data back to the IP it was contacted from, which shouldn't be possible because the server is outside the Amazon cloud.

I might miss something really obvious here. I added a command to *rc.local* (running CENT OS on my ec2 instance) that associates the elastic IP to the server upon startup by using *ec2-associate-address*, and this seemed to help make a MySQL connection to another outside server working, but no luck with the above mentioned API.

To rule out one thing - the API is accessed through HTTPS, with ports 80 and 443 (and a mysql port) enabled in security groups and tested. The domain and SSL are running fine.

Any hint highly appreciated - I searched a lot already, but couldn't find anything useful so far.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like both IPs (private and elastic) are active in your VM.  Check by running `ifconfig -a`.  If that's what's happening then the IP that gets used for external traffic will depend on the remote address and your VM's routing table.  It could even vary from one connection to the next.

If that's what's going on then the quickest fix would be to `ifconfig down` the interface that has the private address.  That should leave only the elastic address for all external connections.   If that resolves the problem then you can script something that downs the private IP automatically after the elastic IP has been made active, or if the elastic IP will be permanently assigned to this VM and you really don't need the private IP then you can permanently disassociate the private IP from this VM.

Comment: Thanks. The elastic IP doesn't show up in ipconfig at all - eth0 is using the private IP and then there's only lo on 127.0.0.1 - that's it.

Comment: Weird.  Are you sure that the MySQL connection used the elastic IP?  When I switched to an elastic IP for my VM I did it through the AWS web GUI so I don't know if you need additional steps when you do it by using the CLI inside the VM.  Does the web GUI look correct for your VM?

Comment: Looks correct and I'm sure MySQL used the elastic IP since I only authorized access from the elastic IP to the db. However, I might have made a simple mistake here: I only checked apache variables/php globals from a domain that is hosted on the ec2 server. But when I access a site outside the amazon cloud, the elastic IP turns up properly. Which means that the reason for my API connection not working properly is most likely different.

Comment: Problem solved - though the vendor had claimed that my elastic IP was granted access, it was still denied (eventually used Lynx to prove it). That solved everything. In case someone else is wondering - Amazon ec2 servers show the internal IP in PHP globals inside the Amazon cloud (maybe same region only?) but the elastic IP - if assigned - when outside the cloud.